# Why isn't the Mouse.DoubleClick functioning properly when the Coded UI test is executed via MTM?

Tags: wpf, automated-tests, coded-ui-tests, mtm

What I'm trying to is to double click on a row in a WPF datagrid. To achieve this I'm using the following code:

```
WpfTable invoiceList = new WpfTable(base.MainWindow);
invoiceList.SearchProperties.Add(WpfTable.PropertyNames.AutomationId, "datagridID");
invoiceList.WaitForControlReady(15000);

Mouse.DoubleClick(invoiceList.GetRow(0));
```

When I run this on my machine the test passes but when I run the same test via MTM I get the following error:

> Test method
>   org.Application.Automation.TestCases.CommentsTests.VerifyExistingCommentsTest
>   threw exception: 
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Extension.PlaybackFailureException:
>   Cannot perform 'DoubleClick' on the control. Additional Details: 
>   TechnologyName:  'UIA' ControlType:  'Row' FrameworkId:  'WPF'  --->
>   System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Error HRESULT E_FAIL has
>   been returned from a call to a COM component.

Could someone point in the right direction as to how I could fix this?

Comment: Sorry i am being stupid to ask this, but just want to confirm, will the button or control on which you are double clicking, will it allow you to double click manually?

Comment: Also please check, if your search is rightly pointing to element you are trying to click but not to row or data cell of grid

Comment: @Siva it does let me double click manually. When I run the same (automated) test on my machine it passes but it fails when I run it via MTM though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone else is facing this issue, I changed my code to the following to get it to work.

```
WpfControl row = invoiceList.GetRow(0);
row.WaitForControlReady();

Mouse.DoubleClick(new System.Drawing.Point(row.BoundingRectangle.X + row.BoundingRectangle.Width, row.BoundingRectangle.Y + row.BoundingRectangle.Height/2));
```

So instead of double clicking on the WpfRow object, I used the Mouse.DoubleClick(new System.Drawing.Point()) option and passed center point (i.e System.Drawing.Point) as the parameter. As to why the previous approach didn't work, I'm afraid I cannot explain.